# Reading strings of chars and use them at the same time(pascal)

Tags: string, types, pascal

A normal input for the program I´m doing would be 5:3B2F. ,all inserted in the same line and the outputwould be to write 3B2F in base 5.

We have been instructed to read that line as two chars(one for the base, the other for the digits)

The problem I´m having is that I dont know how to go through each individual character and do the nesesary operations at the same time, ignoring the":" and ".", and then I also have to make sure that "digits" from the ":" to the "." to have a max of 7 characters.

Also as Im reading the enrty as char when the base is a number I get an error saying expected char but found smallint

I´m a begginer and we are not allowed to use arrays

```
       num:=0;
        read(base,digits);

        while (base <> '$') and (digits < MAXLENGHT) do
```

how do I check that digits is a certain length)

```
      begin
       num:=(num*base)+digit;
```

(this proces should be repeated for each digit IN "digits" (exept for : and .) which I dont know how to do)

```
      writeln(num);
      read(base,digits)
      end;
```

Comment: Is the `:` always present? If yes, it seems easier to completely readln the line into a string and split it into two parts.

Answer (score 0):

With your example `5:3B2F` what base is the `3B2F` part? I would guess 16 but for sure it must be defined, no?

Read the whole input as a string (say into `inStr: string;`.
Then split the string in two (at the colon) and use the `val()` function to convert the strings to values, first to,  say, `radix: integer` and second to `inValue: integer`. If the second part is hexadecimal you need to add '$' in front of the string, otherwise `val()´ chokes on the string or gives wrong result.

A more interesting way for the noble course of learning would be to use one or two `repeat` - `until` loop with a case statement to extract values from the input:

```
// to extract the requested radix
done := False;
i := 1;
repeat
  c := inStr[i];
  case c of
    '0'..'9': radix := radix * 10 + (ord(c) - Ord('0'));
    ':'     : done := True;
    else    //Show error invalid input and terminate
  end;
  inc(i);
  // show error if i > n, whatever n is
until done ;

// a similar loop and case for cases of characters '0'..'9', 'A'..'F' and 'a'..'f'.
```

In order not to spoil your homework, I leave this for you to work out.